# Unable to to install cocoapods - Error installing cocoapods: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I am tring to install cocoapods is using this command: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

I have tried updating ruby, uninstalling and re-installing ruby just so I can install cocoapods

This is my error below:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

----More error response----

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20231019-2526-1y2jjsl.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.16.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.16.3/gem_make.out
```

1. `sudo gem update —system` I tried running this to update.
2. `xcode-select --install` , also tried this because I saw someone said it worked for them. This too didn't work.

Any one faced this issue and how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Update - How I resolved this issue:

- In `mkmf.log`, you would find the universal-darwinxx file you should have. In my case, it was `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin21`
- Run this command `cd $(xcode-select -p)/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0` to confirm what files you currently have. I found that I had `universal-darwin22`
- After you have confirmed that you have a different file, run this command `sudo ln -sf universal-darwin22 universal-darwin21`. This command creates a symbolic link named `universal-darwin21` that points to `universal-darwin22`.
- This should fix the issue. Now, when you run the command `sudo gem install cocoapods` again, you should be able to install it without issues